# Rotating Room by 90 degrees (vertical layout)

Tags: altium

I am working on some simple project in [Altium Designer](http://www.altium.com/) and I have created `Power Supply Room`:
[image: Horizontal Room]
How do I **rotate** this room by **90 degrees** for following result (following screenshot is result of **rotating screenshot, not room itself)**:
[image: Rotated room]

Comment: Click the room to drag it, while dragging to move, press "spacebar".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @Wesley Lee said, I've **selected** the room, pressed `M` (for **Move**), selected `D` (for **Drag**) and then pressed `Space`:
[image: Rotated room]